# Changing product price in Shopware 6 dynamically

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I would like to change the price of a product based on the customer's selection. For example, I'm trying to build a small PDP widget to make customers able to choose the number of candles on a cake or write text on cakes and update the price accordingly. The docs only cover how to change the price by [overwriting the cart's collector/processor](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/change-price-of-item) but I don't want to use this method because of other plugins potentially overwriting the same service. So, is there are any other methods of changing the price of the products by subscribing to an event?

Comment: I believe the collector override described in the doc you linked can be done by multiple modules. Did you try it?

Comment: but if two plugins are overwriting the price collector only the later will be applied, I'm trying to implement a passive solution that has no side effects for other plugins

Comment: Okay, so my assumption was wrong :-( - The design decision behind it is probably, that here needs to be one final price. Chaining the logic and modifying the finial price could work with Symfony decorators. I think also your logic might already work with Custom Products from the professional edition out of the box?

Comment: I don't know much about the professional edition, but my initial thought of implementing this feature was by adding a new input with any custom data I want then listening for `onLineItemAdded` event, and then having access to the line items I would then get the data from the input, set the price using `$lineItem->setPrice` but that would only work when adding the item form the first time and editing the quantity from the cart or quote would reset the price to whatever is defined in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you will need to consider in this one.
Firstly, you will need to save the user input data somewhere (amount of candles, text).
Possibly a separate database table that has a `OneToMany` relationship on cart line items. See this [article](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-custom-complex-data). Und ya, this is also the part where you will hook into the `onLineItemAdd` event & save your user input to that table. You may as well also subscribe to the `onLineItemUpdate` for the same saving logic. You could do the same when removing the item from the cart, although that may not be necessary if you use database's "CASCADE on delete" when implementing your DB table. Meaning once the line item gets removed by the customer (deleted in the DB), your database entry gets deleted as well.

Afterwards, you can then use the `extensions` or otherwise called [associations](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-data-associations) to pull this data on the cart page & the order pages. You can be a little more fancy here, if you look at all the frontend router calls, you will notice that Shopware sometimes passes "Criteria" class you can hook into.

```php
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            OrderRouteRequestEvent::class => 'alterCriteria',
            DocumentOrderCriteriaEvent::class => 'alterCriteria',
        ];
    }

    public function alterCriteria(Event $event): void
    {
        if (method_exists($event, 'getCriteria')) {
            $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('lineItems.myExtension'); // check syntax, could be lineItem.
        }
    }
```

Now you can extend the twig templates to show your candles or text in the order page, cart page, document (invoice) pages.

Secondly, you will have to handle the price. This part will be easier now that you have data saved & being automatically pulled via criteria subscribers. If it's not possible to hook into those events all the time, you will still have an option to manually load your data.

I do not recommend modifying the price itself, but maybe you could look into adding a surcharge instead. Maybe this [article](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/commerce/checkout-concept/cart#price) will be helpful to understand the price flow. You could also see if there are any other plugins out there that implement surcharge logic to see it in action.